# Average of one index of pairs of numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I have a table like [[2,3], [7,6], [12,567],[18,4]]. I need average of elements 2, 7, 12, 18.

```
def average(data):
    temp = []
    for x in data:
        temp.append(x[0])
    return np.average(temp)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: return `np.array(data)[:,0].mean()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use:

```
from statistics import mean
mean(e[0] for e in data)
```

or:

```
np.average([e[0] for e in data])
```

output:

```
9.75
```

or:

```
np.average(np.array(data)[:,0])
```

also @WillemVanOnsem suggestion is great:

```
np.array(data)[:,0].mean()
```

---

```
def average(data):
    np.average([e[0] for e in data])
```

Comment: If you have access to numpy, avoid iterating in Python

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
def average(data):
    return sum(x[0] for x in data)/len(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is an ELI5 version of @kederrac's. If you got that, skip this.

Your solution is correct, we'll just polish it minimally, in one place only.

```
temp = []
for x in data:
    temp.append(x[0])
```

Shrink that to one line with [listcomps](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps). I'm renaming `x` to `row`, I like variable names that click right away.

```
temp = [row[0] for row in data]
```

That's it; the rest of your solution is neat.

```
return np.average(temp)
```

Good luck :)